# How to restore files git deleted during clone

Tags: windows, git

After working on something for a while, I thought I should put it in a git repo. Using gitlab, I created a new repo and cloned it from the command line onto my Windows 7 machine. This created a folder with a .git folder in it. I then copied all the files I'd been working on into the folder. I then noticed that the command line where I had cloned the repo was asking for a password. I entered the wrong password a couple of times and stupidly hit ctrl+c. Next thing I knew, the folder with all my files was gone. It is not in the recycle bin. Is there any way to restore these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, they are lost and git won't help you here. You should rely on file recovery tools to help you recover the files (long, hard and boring process) if you can afford to rewrite your code from scratch.

Buy I could tell you what you did wrong with git and what you should have done to never have been in such a situation...

You should have done :
1. Create a local repository in your project directory with 'git init'. 
2. Do as much development and commits as you want (but at least one...). You are now protected against file deletion! 
3. Once you think it worth to be shared, like you do, create the repository in gitlab. 
4. Add the gitlab repository as a remote in your local repository. 
5. Push the history to the gitlab central repository.

Like that, you should have avoided all the risky action you did and your work is secured at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Standard methods for removed file restoration apply:

1. Suspend any user operations on the HD (don't create/copy/remove files). This will increase your chances when trying to restore.
2. Check if you have the file copies/originals in other folders. You mentioned that you had copied them previously into git folder. May you have them in the original directory?
3. Do you have any backup system running (like Crashplan, etc) ? Check if you have a backup of the files
4. If nothing of the previous helped proceed to the undelete operation - use dedicated utilities like this one for ex.: http://www.ntfsundelete.com